# How to write the create new xml if the xml file is not found in my WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq-to-xml

I currently using an WPF app. Right now, i want to save my data into the XML file. If the xml file is not found in the project, then create a new one. Does anyone can teach me how?

i think the code will be something like this

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadXML();
     }

public void loadXML()
{
    xDocument doc = xDocument.load("MyXmlFile.xml");

    if(doc.exist== false)
    {
     //create new xml
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for the existence of the file before you go anywhere near XML - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.exists.aspx - so `if(!FileInfo.Exists("MyXmlFile.xml"))` then create the XML File

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest thing do to in this instance is to use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) to check if the file actually exists on disk. If it doesn't, then we can save it, otherwise we load it:

```
public void loadXML()
{
    XDocument document = new XDocument();

    if(!File.Exists("MyXmlFile.xml")){
        //Populate with data here if necessary, then save to make sure it exists
        document.Save("MyXmlFile.xml");
    }
    else{
        //We know it exists so we can load it
        document.load("MyXmlFile.xml");
    }

    //Continue to work with document


}
```

Comment: i cant find the "FileInfo.Exists" in my visual studio. Is that any library i need to import 1st?

Comment: You'll need to include `using System.IO` in your class with your other usings. Alternatively, you can write `!System.IO.FileInfo.Exists(` but I find that rather less useful.

Comment: The new file was create successfully but there is an error: The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyProject.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. 
And one more, i use the "file.exists" because i cant found the "FileInfo.Exists".

Comment: @0070 Yes, that's my fault, I meant File.Exists which is the static utility method, rather than FileInfo.Exists which requires you to construct the class first. I've updated the answer with this - thanks for spotting it! You should put a breakpoint in loadXML to diagnose exactly where the error is being thrown (if it is being thrown in there)